# Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. (Dropdown) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-apk

Hello Flutter Development Experts,
I want to make DropdownButton widget to show given items, but I am facing an error ehich is below descrived. I do not know the exact solution. I tried many things even searced on google but, did not get exact answer.

**Error:**
Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:
Parameter 'onChanged' declared as     'void Function(T?)?'
but argument is 'void Function(Object?)'.
The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
Parameter 'value' declared as     'T?'
but argument is 'String'.
Parameter 'items' declared as     'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'
but argument is 'List<DropdownMenuItem>'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

-------------_-------
I hope it is clear and understandable.

```
String dropDownValue = 'Ahmedabad';

 DropdownButton(
                  value: dropDownValue,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined),
                  items: List.generate(
                    6,
                    (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset('ahmdabaf.jpg'),
                            const Text('Ahmedabad'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                )
```

Comment: Can you include more about `dropDownValue`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh please check.

Answer (score 3):

Try providing data type like

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  value:  // this must be included on DropdownMenuItem's value
```

And make sure to include `value` on `DropdownMenuItem``

```
6,
(index) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value:  , // your string value,
```